# list of n zeros in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

This is probably very easy, but I cannot figure out how to do the equivalent of Python's

```
[0]*n
```

in Haskell, in order to get a list with n zeros.

```
[0]*n
```

doesn't work. Am I obliged to do something like: `[0 | x <-[1..5]]` ?

Comment: Check out the haskell tag info page re. finding functions and other interesting stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
λ> take 5 (repeat 0)
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

Or as @obadz points out, this is even more concise:

```
λ> replicate 5 0
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

I personally don't like the python syntax. `*` means multiplication but it does something else in your case. But that's just my opinion :).

Comment: Or `replicate 5 0`

Comment: `*` works the same for lists and integers; it's repeated addition. `some_list * 3 == 3 * some_list == some_list + some_list + some_list`, where list addition is just concatenation.

Comment: @n.m That comment was in response to Sibi's comment about Python's syntax.

Comment: @chepner: this is indeed kind of consistent by itself. Unfortunately, it's glaringly inconsistent with other use of numerical operators. Consider `numpy.array([0]) * 3`.

Comment: I think we're getting to the point where we would just be discussing the pros and cons of operator overloading vs a proliferation of type-specific operators (or even type-specific functions).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
import Data.Monoid

zeroes = 5 * [0] where (*) = mtimes
```

Answer (score -1):

you can define it yourself (as a toy example)

```
(*) :: [a] -> Int -> [a]                     
(*) xs n = take n $ cycle xs
```

so you can have

```
Prelude> [0]*5                                                      
[0,0,0,0,0]

Prelude> [0,1]*5
[0,1,0,1,0]
```

obviously, by redefining existing operators have "side effects"

```
Prelude> 4*4

<interactive>:169:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that `it' has the inferred type
      it :: forall a. Num [a] => [a]
```

or perhaps `python` interpretation is replicate the list n times (instead of picking n elements from the cycled list elements).  In that case you can define it as

```
(*) :: [a] -> Int -> [a]                                                                                 
(*) xs n = concat $ replicate n xs                                                                       


Prelude> [0]*4                                                                                                        
[0,0,0,0]

Prelude> [0,1]*4                                                                                                      
[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

obviously, this is a toy example and you may want to define another operator or simply a function for this.